# Second shift register 74HC595 with wrong outputs

Tags: shift-register, interference

I have a controlling panel at my wall to control which electrical device is active (because I have only a single 10 A phase and running way to often to the breaker).

The principle is easy: read Input by SerialIn (PushButtons) and double shift my values to 2 daisy chained ShiftOut registers. Both ShiftOuts registers shall output the exact same. The first shows the active channels via LEDs and the second controls an array of relays.

But the second shows wrong outputs. In 4 of 5 cases the second register shows a wrong result. It always outputs at least something, but still mostly wrong. I know (or assume based on measurements) that the µC does what I want it to do because the output of the LEDs is always correct and my oscilloscope shows this as well.

Please help to fix the output of the second register.

Here's my setup:

- for input a 74HC165 (ParallelInSerialOut)
- µC is a ATtiny24
- for output two 74HC959 (SerialInParallelOut)
- 2 dedicated power supplies for data and relays

Additional info:

- added multiple electrolytic capacitors
- 100 nF ceramic caps directly between 5 V and GND of the ICs
- the lines for the daisy chain of the ParallelOut registers is about half a meter
- I added 100 kΩ resistors on shift, storage and data lines of the second 74HC595 to GND (I have read that it could help reducing interferences)
- for now I have NOT added a 47 Ω resistor at the lines yet (I have read that it could help reduce reflections on longer lines)
- I tried to keep the live wire as far away as possible, no difference

That's basically what this is all about:

[image]

*Panel, front*

---

[image]

*Panel, back*

The live wire is going to the front panel because of 2 reasons:

- the panel has a fuse
- the panel has 3 sockets

---

[image]

*Wall, all*

---

[image]

*Wall, detail*

---

The following picture shows the data and the clock for the second 74HC595. There are 16 ticks. After 8 ticks it received the old data of the first 74HC595. After another 8 ticks it received the actual needed data which looks very fine.

Notice the middle part (of the second 8 ticks) where no data high signal occured. The subsequent picture shows that nearly every relay is turned on.

[image]
[image]

I noticed a drop of voltage when a relay goes on. In my thinking its ok because it does not drop too dramatically. It’s about half a volt.

[image]

Finally a schematic. Please understand that I am not an expert in creating those documents.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What’s elkos and LifeWire? Please post a schematic.

Comment: The schematic is not sufficiently detailed. There need to be series resistors on the LEDs, and appropriate bypass capacitors on the ICs. Are these opto-relays? If not, they will need flyback diodes. Provide specs on the power supply. And pay special attention to ground connections, keeping power and signals separate.